# Open word document with web layout in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am currently opening a word document using **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start**(Filename). 
However, the word document requires to automatically open in a web layout. (this is an option when selecting **view** and **Web Layout** in MS Word)

Is there a way to do this with the current method I am using to open this?

Comment: There's no way to change the layout directly using Process.Start. If the file was saved when last closed in this layout it will open automatically in the layout. That means you could write it into the file's Open XML before opening it in Word. Otherwise you need to use the "Interop" (`Word.Application wdApp = new Word.Application();`), then you can control the Word environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set by  below code imp is **WdViewType.wdWebView**

```
  using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
  Word.Application wordApplication = new Word.Application();
 var path="fullpath of docuent"
                 wordApplication.Documents.Open(path);
                wordApplication.Visible = true;
                wordApplication.ActiveWindow.View.Type = WdViewType.wdWebView;
                ;
```